# Statistical test for 3x2 contingency table, with cases:controls matched 1:5 (i.e. non-independent)

Tags: contingency-tables, matching

I am examining a cohort of cases against controls, matched at a 1:5 ratio (on sex, birth year, and residency/postal code at time of diagnosis).

| Education level | Cases (n=206) | Controls (n=957) | p-value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Low | 10(5%) | 81(9%) | ? |
| Mid | 78(38%) | 398(42%) | ? |
| High | 118(57%) | 461(48%) | ? |

I want to examine if the proportions of individuals in each category of education are significantly different between cases and controls (e.g is 57 % highly educated cases a significantly larger proportion than 48 % highly educated controls). Simple enough right, but **I can´t seem to find the correct statistical test for this**.

**Chi-square** does not seem appropriate since the controls are matched against the cases, i.e. the groups are not independent.

**McNemar** does not seem appropriate since the matching is not 1:1, but 1:5, also this is a 3x2 and not a 2x2 table.

A **regression model** does not seem appropriate for just simply comparing proportions between groups, education category by education category.

I would like to find the equivalence of a Chi-Square but for non-independent groups. McNemar is often suggested but like mentioned above, not good if it is not matched *pairs* (i.e. 1:1) and anything larger than a 2x2 table.

Many thanks in advance!

GH

Comment: *"matched at a 1:5 ratio (on sex, birth year, and residency/postal code at time of diagnosis)."* I feel uncomfortable when details of this matching are left out. But, that is just a sidenote, as it is not essential to the analysis of the 2x3 table (although it distracts me in trying to understand what's going on).

Comment: How was this table created and what is the inspiration to investigate the table? The 2x3 table seems to be just the distribution of the counts of the cohort into different categories. And apparently the 'cases' have relatively more people in the high education level than the 'control'. Why would you like to apply a statistical test on this?

Answer (score 1):

First, if people were randomly assigned to case or control, then all you are doing is testing your randomization method. In 1 of 20 cases, they will be significantly different, even if the randomization was perfect. Other statistics that you might do account for this.

Second, chi-square would be fine, if you really want to do a test. But one that accounted for the ordinal nature of education might be better. I often use the Jonckheere-Terpstra test. I think you have misunderstood the meaning of "independence" here. Independent samples means that the people aren't "connected" in some way. For instance, if you had pairs of spouses, that would violate independence. Also, I think you will only want one p value (if any).

Third, this looks a bit like a typical "table 1 analysis".  This would be one row of a typical table 1. I wrote a blog post about why you don't want p values in these. Here is a non-paywall (I hope) link to it. [Do not put p values in your table 1](https://medium.com/peter-flom-the-blog/do-not-put-p-values-in-your-table-1-8aad0d6c92d?sk=eb958b48fa33c86c705cc4097fc1211e). Readers can see that the cases are more educated.

Finally, I don't see anything wrong with regression here, either (again, if you want a test, which I don't think you do).

Comment: Thank you for your input! To clarify - the cases were selected based on a specific diagnosis (they all have a brain disease). The controls were then selected from the general population - every case has five controls, that are of the same sex and birth year as their associated case (but the controls do not have the brain disease). So, controls and cases are dependent and connected I think.

Why would I want just one p-value, and not one for each education category?

You are correct, this table is part of the "background variable" table to describe my cohort. I will read the blog post!

Comment: No, this is not what "dependent" means in this case. It would mean things like doing two treatments on the same person (within subject) or, as I said, on married couples. See e.g. https://www.statology.org/assumption-of-independence/ which says "Many statistical tests make the assumption that observations are independent. This means that no two observations in a dataset are related to each other or affect each other in any way."

Comment: That is interesting. The statisticians I consulted were adamant that if there is a matching between controls and cases, i.e. every control is selected to be of the same age, sex, and social background (=residency/postal code) as their respective case, then there is a dependency in the data. Thus, the data contains several hundred strata, every stratum contains one case, five controls. 
I have used conditional logistic regression in other analysis within my study cohort for this very reason. 
How is this less of a dependency than between a married couple?

Comment: Because, to use the bit I quoted, "the observations do NOT affect each other" and are not related.

Comment: Also, if you Google "chi square for case control studies" you will find lots of examples.

Comment: I see, but I would need to clarify what constitutes an "observation" in my case.
In my table above, would observation nr 1 be that 57% of the cases have education level "high", and observation nr 2 that 48 % of the controls have education level "high". 

And do you mean that even if the controls are matched on the cases, these two observations do not affect each other?

Sorry if I am being slow. This matching/dependency thing has had me confused since the start of the study, and the biostatisticians at my department are unable to explain it clearly (or maybe I just don´t get them).

Comment: An observation is the data on a particular person. Both "observation" and "dependence" are confusing terms.  I don't know how to explain "dependence" better than I have done. But there are certainly articles about it.

Comment: Thank you Peter for your time and input! I will consider what you said about p-values in table one, I agree that the actual group sizes are more interesting than the p-values anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are looking for a *z-test for column proportions*. The z-test compares the proportion of the total frequency of the first column that falls into the first row against the proportion of the total frequency of the second column that falls into the first row and will give you a p-value. It will repeat that procedure for all rows and give you a p-value for each one of the rows, I understand that this is what your are looking for.

That said, I think a Chi-square would work and that Peter Flom's [comment](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/627322/396652) is right and accurate. Misunderstanding with dependent, related and other terms is very common and must be treated with care. Dependent, as he indicates, would be that the value of one sample is directly related to that of the other, for example if you measure the weight of the same person two times with a diet in between. If you measure the weight of two people, no matter how closely matched they are, it will never be dependent if they are not the same person.